# Как сверстать заголовок с подчеркиванием оставшейся части строки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте.
Возможно ли сверстать без js вот такой заголовок (собственно интересует подчеркивание оставшейся части строки):
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Фон у заголовка должен быть прозрачным. и хотелось бы обойтись без вложенных спанов, т.к. хочется дать возможность контент-менеджеру добавлять такие заголовки в текст просто выбрав класс из списка.

Comment: "Возможно ли сверстать без js" и тег "javascript" - а что, логично)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать такое вот решение:

```css
.test:after {
     display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
      content: '';  
      margin-top: 13px;
      margin-left: 3px;
      position: absolute;
}

span.test {
  display: block;  
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">text</span>
```

В общем, то - то же самое что и в ответе от Special, но работает с заголовком в несколько строк (подчеркивание переносится на нижнюю строчку) и не добавляет скрол снизу

Пример тут: http://jsfiddle.net/tk3bduop/3/

Comment: Блин, точно, overflow:hidden ведь можно повесить на сам элемент) Благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Примерно то же, что и у [@FAngel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415042/176792), но может быть немного полегче:

```css
body {
    background: #ccc;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: brown;
    font: 20px sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<h1>Некий заголовок некоего раздела страницы</h1>
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/2b225ehn/

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот решение http://jsfiddle.net/juttnayo/

Comment: Это решение очевидно. Нужно, чтобы полоска занимала оставшуюся часть строки, а не 100%. Вернее, не влекла за собой горизонтальный скролл.

Comment: Было бы неплохо дублировать куски кода непосредственно в ответе. Если ссылка "умрет" ваш ответ потеряет смысл.

Answer (score 0):

Заголовок должен умещаться в одну строку, иначе скролл.
http://jsfiddle.net/2s2nqdn7/

```
<h1>Какой-то заголовок&#8239;</h1>
```

Как избавиться от пробела для отступа не придумал. Но сама идея работает и без него.

```
h1 {
  display: table-row;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

h1:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
}
```